# useEffectHook in web form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to use the `useEffect` hook to pre-populate some form data but cannot get it to work quite right.

I can get the data to load in the fields by refreshing the page - then all works ok - this is when the code is set as shown in the example.

I can get the data loaded on the form when it first loads, by adding  'state' in the `[]` on the `useEffect`, but then I cannot change the data in the form (the action from redux is re-fired at each change on the form and overwrites anything that has been typed in).
loading is returned as part of the reducer, which first sets it to true and then to false once the payload is returned.

```
const EditForm = ({ reduxstore: {state, loading},  callreduxfunction, match, history}) => {

     const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        _id: '',
        field1: ''
     })   

     useEffect( () => {
         callreduxfunction(match.params.id);
         setFormData({
            _id: match.params.id,
            field1: !loading ? state.field1 : ''
         });   

    }, [loading,  callreduxfunction, match]);

    )
}
```

I'm pretty new to react and just started using hooks -- would really appreciate any help on that one!

Comment: What is your purpose of using useEffect ? It is not clear from your question. If you answer, I can help.

Comment: What does `callreduxfunction` do? Where is `state` initialised? Where is `loading` defined and what makes it change? If you want to pre-populate your form, why do you want to repeat that, every time `loading` changes? There is way too few information to adequately answer your question.

Comment: @FurkanO useEffect is to return data from an api call (via redux action/reducer) which is the callreduxfuntion part and setting the form data to the values returned by the api.

Comment: @viviejed ok, I see. But why did you provide the second params to useEffect? Do you need to do it more than once for the same component?

Comment: @FurkanO no I don't and I have tried removing it but it makes no difference, it seems the issue is the [state] which i pull from the redux store... if I don't include that the data isn't loaded when the page is first rendered, if I do then it re-fires at each change and overwrites the changes on the form...

Comment: @viviejed but why don t you keep the redux state as the source of truth, so that avoid keeping the same data in the component? So that, you would have your second param to useEffect as [], to call it once when the component mounts, then just read from redux and write to redux too..

Comment: @FurkanO I've tried that, thinking it was the logical way of doing this - but it does't work when I do.

Comment: @viviejed you should make it work, because coupling the data management as you are trying to do in this case is not the best practice, if you don t have any extraordinary need. You should try harder to keep redux as source of truth. You can post / update your question about how you can not do it. I can help.

Comment: @FurkanO - yes keeping redux as the source of truth is what I am trying to achieve, at least when the form first loads. The problem is that if I don't include the functioncall to redux and the state from redux, the data is not returned on the form. Though I can see the function call to redux works ok as I am loading different fields on the form depending on the data returned and that bit does work on load of the page, it's only the setState part that seems to fail.

Comment: I always keep redux as the source of truth for form data management. I rarely use reacts internal state management.

Comment: Not sure how to do that? @FurkanO

Comment: So do you know how to update redux state? And also read from redux state? If answer is yes to both questions, you can accomlish setting and reading form values.

Comment: so @FurkanO making sure I have this right, what you're saying is to not use the useState hook and to only use the data from redux?

Comment: Yep. Definetely.

Comment: @FurkanO what woud the onChange look like? at the moment I have const onChange = e =>
            setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

Comment: @viviejed sounds good. but if there is a problem, please try to debug all from redux dev tool. Like, check if the action works as you expected, by checking the state and next state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, in the end I changed the code to this:

```
const EditForm = ({ reduxstore: {state, loading},  callreduxfunction, match, history}) => {

         const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
            _id: '',
            field1: ''
         })   

         useEffect( () => {
             callreduxfunction(match.params.id);
             setFormData({
                _id: match.params.id,
                field1: !loading ? state.field1 : ''
             });   

        }, [state._id]);

        )
    }
```

This stopped the redux call from being repeated after the inital load as the id doesn't change. For this to work, I also had to set the initial state of the "state" to an empty object in my reducer (it was set to null).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `useEffect` hooks, one for initialization and one for handling updates:

```
...
// When loading for the first time (Initialization)
useEffect( () => {
         // do something 

}, [ ]);

// After updating state
useEffect( () => {
         callreduxfunction(match.params.id);
         setFormData({
            _id: match.params.id,
            field1: !loading ? state.field1 : ''
         });   

}, [loading,  callreduxfunction, match]);
...
```